# How to define a condition for the distance matrix?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

There is a set of points on the plane $(x_i, y_i)$, $i = 1, 2, ...., n$. Each point has a binary label: $0$ or $1$.

Different points denoted by yellow (0) and blue (1) in the Figure.

[image]

It is required to build a spatial graph and then find the minimum spanning tree. In the graph, a vertex is a point, and edges are added according to two conditions:

1. an edge between vertices labeled $0$ is prohibited,
2. the degree of the vertex labeled $0$ must be equal to $1$.

To constuct a graph, I defined the distance matrix between all pairs of points:

\begin{equation*}
d((x_i, y_i), (x_j, y_j)) = 
 \begin{cases}
   \infty, &\text{if $(x_i, y_i)$ and $(x_j, y_j)$ labeled by $0$ both}\\
   \sqrt{(x_i- x_j)^2 + (y_i - y_j)^2}, & \text{otherwise}
 \end{cases}
\end{equation*}

**Problem:** using the formula above, I don't know how to implement the condition (2). The current solution is to add a new point and get two edges between blue vertecies.

**Question:** How to define the condition (2) for calculating the distance matrix?

**My idea**. The distance matrix is symmetric. For each point labeled with $0$ in a column of the distance matrix, put all elements to infinity except the minimum one. In this case we will have only one edge.

**Edit after @DavidG.Stork's comment.**

I followed steps 1-2. I am currently working on the Step 3. I need to remove the nodes marked with red lines. My problem is the conditions. I am looking for a rule to distinguish between marked/non-marked nodes.

[image]

Comment: I would 1) find the minimum spanning tree of the blue vertices, 2) join each yellow vertex to its nearest blue vertex, 3) eliminate any blue vertex not connected to a yellow vertex and connect its (blue) neighbors.  (Repeat step 3 as necessary).

Comment: @DavidG.Stork, thank you for the comment, Steps 1 and 2 are quite understandable for me. But step 3 is little bit hard for realisation. After steps 1-3, is the minimum spanning tree guaranteed to be unique?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork, I followed steps 1-2. I am currently working on the Step 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would:

1. find the minimum spanning tree of the blue vertices,
2. join each yellow vertex to its nearest blue vertex,
3. eliminate any blue vertex not connected to a yellow vertex and connect its (blue) neighbors

Repeat step 3 as necessary...